# Python web app con Flask - Importar librerias en plantillas html

Tags: flask

repliqué el ejemplo de flask [machine learning model en web](https://medium.com/fintechexplained/flask-host-your-python-machine-learning-model-on-web-b598151886d)  de Farhad Malik y me funciono bien pero al intentar incluir librerías en las plantillas HTML me sale el error jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'pandas' is undefined, quisiera saber si alguien sabe cuál es el problema.

Este es mi .py principal

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

app = Flask('stoke_pricer')

@app.route('/')
def show_predict_stock_form():
    return render_template('predictorform.html')

@app.route('/resultsform', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def results():
    form = request.form
    if request.method == 'POST':
       model = joblib.load('ML1Obesidad_RF.pkl')
       inp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['euexfreq', 'eustreason', 'eugenhth', 'ertseat', 'eufastfdfrq'])
       [...]
       predicted_stock_price = model.predict_proba(inp)[0][1]
       return render_template('resultsform.html', inp=inp,   predicted_price=predicted_stock_price)
    else:
        return render_template('resultsform.html', predicted_price=request.method)

app.run("localhost", "9999", debug=True)
```

y este es el HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Resultados</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h3>Inputs:</h3>
 <div>
 {% import pandas as pd %}
 {% print(pd.DataFrame.transpose(inp)) %}
 </div>
 
 <h3>Salida:</h3>
 <div>Probabilidad de padecer obesidad<strong>{% print(": {:.2f}".format(predicted_price*100)) %}% </strong> </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bro el problema es simple
crea una carpeta templates dentro pon tus documentos .html
y listo jeje parece broma pero yo pase indagando todo el internet y era eso. plop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema viene con la importación, eso lo dejas al backend de flask.

En tu código, tienes:

```
inp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['euexfreq', 'eustreason', 'eugenhth', 'ertseat', 'eufastfdfrq'])
[...]
predicted_stock_price = model.predict_proba(inp)[0][1]
return render_template('resultsform.html', inp=inp, predicted_price=predicted_stock_price)
```

En esta última línea está el problema, le estás pasando la variable de una manera que le hace falta trabajar, debería ser:

```
return render_template('resultsform.html', inp=[inp.to_html(classes='data')], predicted_price=predicted_stock_price)
```

Con esto hecho, en tu plantilla, reemplaza:

```
<div>
    {% import pandas as pd %}
    {% print(pd.DataFrame.transpose(inp)) %}
</div>
```

Por esto:

```
{% for table in inp %}
    {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Debería salirte algo :D

Comment: Muchas gracias fredyfx resolvió mi problema, pero ¿entonces en las plantillas renderizadas con render_template() no puedo usar funciones de las librerías de python?

Comment: Me alegra saberlo hermano :D La verdad, desconozco si eso es posible en python y flask.

Comment: @ALF-100 puedes utilizar algunas funciones por defecto que trae JINJA2 o tambien puedes escribir las tuyas propias e inicializarlas en el __init__.py de tu proyecto usando: app.jinja_env.globals.update(tu_funcion=tu_funcion). Ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036082/call-a-python-function-from-jinja2